# Transfer Database from SQL-Server 2005 to SQL-Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, smo

I have an existing application that transfers a Database from a source server to a target server via SMO "Transfer". We transfer only the data.

Both SQL-Servers are 2005.

Now we upgrade the target server to SQL-Server 2008. Will the transfer via SMO still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't work out of the box. I had to use the SMO-dll of SQL Server 2008. They have slightly different names.
It was not necessary to change code.

My databases where set to use SQLServer 2005 compatibility mode. I had to change them to native SQLServer 2008 mode.

Answer (score 1):

yes. they should. SMO hasn't really changed between version.